# How to strip all tags except br in re.compile python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a code as below which strips all tags:

```
import re

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext

payload = '<a href="asdasda.htm">I am inside</a><br/><p>Tagsssss</p>'
print cleanhtml(payload)
```

How to ignore `<br>` tags and just remove all the other tags? This code append all lines together.

Comment: By `<(?!br\b).*?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Negative Lookahead:

```
<(?!br).*?>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/91s8rW/1

```
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile(r'<(?!br).*?>')
    cleantext = cleanr.sub('', raw_html)
    return cleantext
```

For detect multiple `br` tags and replace with one you can use following regex:

```
re.sub(r'(<br>)+', r'\1', your_text)
```

Demo:

```
In [7]: re.sub(r'(<br>)+', r'\1', 'foobar<br><br><br>barbaz')
Out[7]: 'foobar<br>barbaz'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to detect multiple br tags and replace it with one?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)